# Return PNG image from Django views is damaged

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on a Django(2) project in which I need to return a PNG image as HttpResponse when I return this image in the form of a zip archive it returns the image correctly, but when I return the PNG image directly it damaged the image.

Here's my code:

**How it's writing the image:**

```
img_resized = cv2.resize(seg_image, dsize)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'img/MaskedImage.png'), img_resized)
```

**How it's returning the Image:**

```
response = HttpResponse(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'img/MaskedImage.png'), content_type='image/png')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=MaskedImage.png'

    return response
```

It returns an Image with the name `MaskedImage.pn` but the image is damaged, not able to open.

What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You write the path as *content*, not the content of the file...

Comment: Note that this approach will not work well if you have multiple concurrent users, as each of them will be writing to the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to read the image data. You're currently returning a response with just the image path.

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'img/MaskedImage.png'), 'rb') as fp:
    response = HttpResponse(fp.read(), content_type='image/png')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=MaskedImage.png'
    return response
```